# Possibly to copy files from one farm to another in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would be doing this from a custom workflow activity.

Does anyone know if this has been done before?  Any suggestions on where to start?

I am an admin on both farms.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?  WSS, MOSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you look into using the Copy web service provided by SharePoint

/_vti_bin/copy.asmx

Comment: I think web services are a good idea (Credentials will probably be easier to manage.. assuming they are different between farms).

Answer (score 0):

Use web client and copy.asmx check this link might help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/4556873e-e2e0-4b26-99f2-70f0b0e50c2c